# Deploy EJB 3 as separate project and access through the servlet in Websphere 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I have created sample EJB 3 application with annotation in WebSphere 7. It is like this.

1. The local interface

   ```
   @Local
   public interface ICalLocalBean{     

   public int add(int a, int b);

   }
   ```
2. Implementation of EJB.

   ```
   @Stateless
   public class CalcEJBean implements ICalLocalBean {

   @Override
   public int add(int a, int b) {
       return a + b;
   }

   }
   ```
3. Access the EJB inside the servlet.

   ```
   public class CalcServlet extends HttpServlet {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @EJB
   private ICalLocalBean iCalLocalBean;    

   ...

   }
   ```

I have added the EJB module as a deployment assembly in my client project EAR. I can success fully call the add method in this way. But I want to deploy this EJB module as separate application in WebSphere server and call the add method. How can I do this. Please help me ...

Answer (score 0):

Per section 3.2.2 of the EJB 3.1 specification:

> Access to an enterprise bean through the local client view is only
>   required to be supported for local clients packaged within the same
>   application as the enterprise bean that provides the local client
>   view. Compliant implementations of this specification may optionally
>   support access to the local client view of an enterprise bean from a
>   local client packaged in a different application. The configuration
>   requirements for inter-application access to the local client view are
>   vendor-specific and are outside the scope of this specification.
>   Applications relying on inter-application access to the local client
>   view are non-portable.

That said, WebSphere does support this with some limitations.  See the Local Client Views section of the [EJB Modules](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cejb_emod.html) topic in the InfoCenter for more information.